# Why do social buttons get cut and not get fully displayed

Tags: html, css, reveal.js

I am using social share buttons (Facebook,twitter,G+,stumplupon) on my website.

But for some reason,all of these buttons are getting cut in height and width,i.e. they are not appearing fully

After hours of troubleshooting,i found out that,If i zoom out the page (in google chrome using ctrl and scroll back) the buttons appear normal.Hence,There is something fishy about CSS,perhaps something is specified in %s.

However,the height and width of most elements is set to 100%.Also I have never specified CSS for social buttons.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Mau5/6/).I am using a reveal.js code.I have tried altering the iframe css as some social buttons are iframes,but in vain.

```
.reveal img, .reveal video, .reveal iframe {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%
}
```

Edit:For facebook button,height attribute is supported.Hence fb buttons can be displayed normally.However for G+,twitter,stumpleupon the height attributed is not supported.
There is something in CSS which is cutting the buttons :( Inspect element is not giving any hints :(

Answer (score 0):

As an example, the iframe for the Facebook button is specifically set to `height:24px`.

Comment: Thanks for replying.Yes,this solves the issue only for fb buttons.For other buttons,height attribute is not supported.

Comment: I see `height:24px` on the google button iframe and `height:20px` on the Twitter button iframe..

Comment: Inspecting the iframes of your fiddle.